# Speed up admin-ajax.php request in CPT filters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have custom post types with JS filtering (based on category). There are simple html boxes + php code with ACF fields what display after select category.

Problem is it take 1 second or more to load all this html boxes so its not so smooth.

This is my JS (file filters.js):

```
(function($){
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var category = $(this).data('category');

            $.ajax({
                url:wp_ajax.ajax_url,
                data: { action: 'filter', category: category },
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('.js-filter').html(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    console.warn(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

This is html of box what is loaded (file content_pozice_box.php)

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"><div class="vypis_pozice">
    <div class="projekt-wrapper">
    <?php
    $projekt = get_field('projekt');
if( get_field('projekt') == 'XXX' ) {
    ?>
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="https://YYY.png" class="logo-wrapper-img">
    </div><?php
} 
            if( get_field('projekt') == 'YYY' ) {
    ?>
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="https://XXX.png" class="logo-wrapper-img">
    </div>
        <?php
} 
    ?>
    <div class="field_projekt"><h3><?php the_field('projekt');?></h3><div class="field_AAA">AAA: 
        <?php if ( get_field( 'AAA' ) ): ?>
        <?php the_field('AAA');?>
<?php else: // field_name returned false ?>
dohodou
<?php endif; // end of if field_name logic ?>
        </div></div>
    </div>
    <?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
    <div class="location-wrapper">
        <div class="BBB"><img src="https://BBB.png"><?php the_field('BBB');?></div>
        <div class="CCC"><img src="https://CCC.png"><?php the_field('CCC');?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="DDD"><?php $cat = get_the_category(); echo $cat[0]->cat_name; ?></div><div class="job-button">Otevřít</div>
    </div></a>
```

PHP (loading JS, Ajax, function)

```
function load_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/' . 'template-parts/' .'filters.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

    wp_localize_script('ajax' , 'wp_ajax',
        array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
        );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax' );

function filter_ajax() {


$category = $_POST['category'];

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'pozice',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

if(isset($category)) {
    $args['category__in'] = array($category);
}

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
include("content_pozice_box.php");
            endwhile;
        endif;
            wp_reset_postdata(); 


    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve all your problems but the first thing you should do is reduce your database calls. `get_field('projekt')` is called 4 times, which runs for every iteration of your loop. Oddly, you've already set it to a variable:

```
$projekt = get_field('projekt');
```

But you're not using the variable anywhere. So try replacing that first, so that it only runs once per iteration:

```
if ( $projekt ) {...}
```

While you're at it you should always escape output for security's sake. I.E. Instead of `<h3><?php the_field('projekt');?></h3>` replace with `<h3><?php echo esc_html( $projekt ); ?></h3>`.

To find other sources of inefficiencies you might try the Query Monitor plugin, as well as your browser's dev tools. I'm not sure about your JS. It looks fine to me but perhaps someone else here will notice something.